# Вместо русского текста непонятные символы

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть `TextBlock`, который принимает текст из файла по `DownloadString`.

Код:`<TextBlock x:Name="DescriptionTxt" Margin="9,9,9,120" Text="[Описание]" FontSize="16" Foreground="LightGray" TextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol"/>`

Текст: `Тест123`

На выходе:

[image: Не понятный текст]

Почему так происходит?

Comment: А что в строке до вывода её в TextBlock? Посмотрите.

Comment: РўРµСЃС‚123, тоже самое. Я решил посмотреть через сайт, и он почему-то искажает русский текст.

Comment: Видимо вы читаете в неверной кодировке с сайта

Comment: И правда, сайт выдаёт мне текст в не той кодировке.

Comment: Ваш текст Тест123 в кодировке utf8, а вы читаете его в кодировке Encoding.Default, то есть cp1251. Как правильно было написано в удалённом ответе, указывайте кодировку при получении строки (но не cp1251, а utf8).

Answer (score 2):

Указывай кодировку при чтении файла!

```
StreamReader sr = new streamReader (@"файл", Encoding.GetEncoding(1251))
```

Comment: Удаленный ответ восстановил, спасибо VladD, за поддержку
 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/10105/vladd

Answer (score 2):

Оказывается сайт, с которого я получаю строку, отправляет её в не той кодировке.
Надо в `UTF-8`, а у меня `Windows-1251`. Решил проблему так:

```
 webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```